# Different results between python map and numpy vectorize

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

My understanding is that (one use of) numpy's vectorize allows me to send an array to a function that normally only takes scalars, instead of using the built in map function (in combination with a lambda function or the like). However, under the following scenario I am getting different results when I use map vs numpy.vectorize and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
import numpy as np

def basis2(dim, k, x):
    y = np.array([-0.2, -0.13, -0.06, 0, 0.02, 0.06, 0.15, 0.3, 0.8,
                  1.6, 3.1, 6.1, 10.1, 15.1, 23.1, 30.1, 35.0, 40.0, 45.0, 50.0, 55.0])

    if x < y[k] or x > y[k + dim + 1]:
        return 0

    elif dim != 0:
        ret = ((x - y[k]) / (y[k + dim] - y[k])) * basis2(dim - 1, k, x) + (
            (y[k + dim + 1] - x) / (y[k + dim + 1] - y[k + 1])) * basis2(dim - 1, k + 1, x)
        return ret

    else:
        return 1.0

w = np.array([20.0, 23.1, 30.0])
func = lambda x: basis2(3, 14, x)
vec = map(func, w)

func2 = np.vectorize(basis2)
vec2 = func2(3, 14, w)

print vec  # = [0, 0.0, 0.23335417007039491]
print vec2  # = [0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the docstring says:

The data type of the output of `vectorized` is determined by calling
the function with the first element of the input.  This can be avoided
by specifying the `otypes` argument.

you need to add a `otypes` argument:

```
func2 = np.vectorize(basis2, otypes="d")
```

or change `return 0` to `return 0.0` in `basis2()`.